# C++ dereference happens after implicit conversion

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, dereference

Today I saw that when trying to dereference an argument in a function call, the implicit conversion happens before the actual dereference operation (I believe only if the original type does not support dereference).

This observation can be seen here:

```
struct A{};


struct C
{
    C(const A&)
    {

    }
};


C operator*(const C&);

double f(C);


template <typename T>
struct t
{
    static const bool value = sizeof(f(**static_cast<T*>(NULL))) == sizeof(double);
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    t<A>::value;
}
```

Does the C++ standard explicitly mention this behaviour? Thank you.

Comment: [This implicit conversion references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) lists "when the expression is used as an operand with an operator that expects T2". In your case `T1` is `A`, and `T2` is `C`. You perform the unary dereference operator on the `A` object, there is no such operator defined, but there is one for `C` which the type `A` can be converted to. Then the unary dereference operator is used.

Comment: Please explain how it can be seen there, as the program has no observable behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo the code would give a diagnostic (no matching overload of `f`) if the conversion didn't happen

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ok, so the fact that this happens in a function call has no relevance, correct?

Comment: It might have something to do with the function call accepting a `C`. If you overload `f` to take an `A` object I think it would be a different result, and the conversion would not be needed and you would get an error about dereferencing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried replacing f(C) with f(A) and the conversion of A to C still happens before the dereferencing, but then the compiler complains that it cannot convert from C back to A.

Comment: @molbdnilo as M.M's comment said, the program would not compile.

Comment: Just ran your code in MSVC 2017 15.7.0 (today's update) and the `t<a>::value` is `true`. Could your observation be an artifact of the compiler you are using?

Comment: @YePhIcK If the code compiles, t<A>::value should always be true.

Comment: Function call is a red herring. In `**static_cast<T*>(NULL)`, you essentially have `A a; *a;` The only way to make `*a` compile is as `operator*(C(a))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at this expression:

```
f(**static_cast<A*>(NULL))
```

From inner-most to outer-most, `static_cast<A*>(NULL)` is an `A*` (though prefer `nullptr` to `NULL`, and also prefer using `std::declval<A*>()` to get "something of type `A*`" rather than the old casting of null pointer approach).

Next, `*(a prvalue of type A*)` gives you an lvalue of type `A`. That's just what pointer dereference means and it isn't overloadable. It's nice when things are easy to reason about.

Next, `*(an lvalue of type A)`. In order to figure out what that means, we [transform](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#2) the call to function-notation, and our set of candidates are:

- [`A::operator*()`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.1)
- [`operator*(a)`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.2), doing unqualified lookup on `operator*()` in the context of the expression.
- [built-in](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#6) candidates.

The first bullet doesn't find anything, there is no `A::operator*()`. The second bullet, unqualified lookup on `operator*()` will find the function `C operator*(const C&);` because it is in scope. It is a viable candidate, because `A` is convertible to `C` via `C(A const&)`. The third bullet has no viable candidate.

As we only have one viable candidate, it's trivially the best viable candidate - so `*(lvalue of type A)` gives us a prvalue of type `C`.

To specifically answer your question:

> the implicit conversion happens before the actual dereference operation

Yes, the conversion has to happen in order to resolve the dereference operation. Although it's not actually a "dereference", it's just a unary `operator*()`.

Lastly, `f(prvalue of type C)` invokes the one `f` we have that gives us `double`.

---

Note that in modern C++, I'd suggest writing the check as something closer to:

```
template <typename T>
struct t
    : std::is_same<
        decltype(f(*std::declval<T>())), // <== the type we get when we call f
                                         // on a dereferenced T
        double>
{ };
```

Comment: @xskxzr It would be if it were in an evaluated context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The function call made me think it was the one responsible for the implicit conversion, but the operator*() found in the context is the one that requires it first, as you pointed out.